# Yii2 : Vote for a Post in AJAX or Pjax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm a begginer in Yii2 framework.

I work on a forum :

In the forum/posts method, there is a list of posts about the topic.

Each Post have a score which I want up and down in AJAX.

In my view `posts.php`, I open a Pjax block :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
      Votes : <?= $val['score'] ?>
      <?= Html::a('+', ['/post/voteup','id'=>$val['id']]) ?>
      <?= Html::a('-', ['/post/votedown','id'=>$val['id']]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**In my PostController :**

```
public function actionVoteup($id){
    //Update request
    $postRepo=new PostRepository();
    $postRepo->vote('plus', "id=$id");
    $post=$postRepo->getAll("id=$id");

    return $this->renderAjax('vote', ['id'=>$id, 'score'=>$post[0]['score']]);

}
```

**You can see I return the Vote.php view in Ajax, same code Pjax.**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    Votes : <?= $score ?>
    <?= Html::a('+', ['/post/voteup','id'=>$id]) ?>
    <?= Html::a('-', ['/post/votedown','id'=>$id]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

The update request is OK but I have some problems/questions :

- Ex : I want to up the 2nd post score, I click, OK, I click a second time, the part of view which is refresh is the 1st Post score (but in database, it's the good score updated).
  I think the problem is about my part of view that I return in my `actionVoteup()`.
  Should I return forum/posts or post/vote ?
- When I click in the link, my URL is : `post/voteup` ; how can I return in the original URL forum/posts ?

I don't really understand how works Pjax, and I didn't find good examples about its utilisation.

Thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'enablePushState' => false` in `Pjax` attribute.

Like as

`<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>`

For more info. Visit this [Demo](http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/vote)

Comment: Thanks ! It's ok for the URL.
I'll try to resolve my first problem now :)